# Using the jQuery Cycle plugin with the ScrollTo plugin

Tags: jquery, cycle, scrollto, pager

I am using the .cycle plugin to to cycle through images. I have the scrollTo plugin setup on my pager. It scrolls with the .click function but doesn't scroll as it cycles. How do I get it to scroll the pager with every cycle?

```
        $(document).ready(init);

        function init() {
    var titles = ['1913', '1918', '1927', '1935', '1950', '1963', '1977', '1980', '1983', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1988-1999', '1990', '1992', '1993', '1993-1995', '1994', '1995', '1999', '1999', '2000', '2003', '2003', '2003', '2003', '2006', '2007-2008', '2011', '2011', '2013'];
    // dynamically add a div to hold the slideshow's pager
    $("#allCardContainer").before('<div id="pager"></div>');

    // now to use the cycle plugin
    $("#allCardContainer").cycle({
        pause: 1,
        pager: "#pager",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            return '<a class="scroll" id="link' + [index] + '" href="#' + [index] + '">' + titles[index] + '</a>';

        }

    });



    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#allCardContainer').cycle('pause');
        $('#pager').scrollTo($(this), 1500, { axis: 'x', offset:-50 });
    });


}
```

So the code creates the pager div then cycles through the images. The second function pauses the cycle and scrolls the pager to the left. How do I make that scroll to fire on every cycle so my selected pager div is always in the same spot and always visible?

EDIT:

If I try this my click works great but the pager doesn't scroll during cycle.

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
    var titles = ['1913', '1918', '1927', '1935', '1950', '1963', '1977', '1980', '1983', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1988-1999', '1990', '1992', '1993', '1993-1995', '1994', '1995', '1999', '1999', '2000', '2003', '2003', '2003', '2003', '2006', '2007-2008', '2011', '2011', '2013'];
    // dynamically add a div to hold the slideshow's pager
    $("#allCardContainer").before('<div id="pager"></div>');

    // now to use the cycle plugin
    $("#allCardContainer").cycle({
        pause: 1,
        pager: "#pager",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            return '<a class="scroll" id="link' + [index] + '" href="#' + [index] + '">' + titles[index] + '</a>'; 
        },
        before: slideScroll(false)
    });

    function slideScroll(clicked) {
        if (clicked) {
            //$('#allCardContainer').cycle('pause');
            $('#pager').scrollTo($('.activeSlide'), 1500, { axis: 'x', offset: -83 });
        }
        else {
            $('#pager').scrollTo($('.activeSlide'), 1500, { axis: 'x', offset: -20 });
            alert('sliding');
        }
    }

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
        slideScroll(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provied jsfiddle of this in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to be doing what you want in the **before** option of cycle

```
// now to use the cycle plugin
$("#allCardContainer").cycle({
    pause: 1,
    pager: "#pager",
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
        return '<a class="scroll" id="link' + [index] + '" href="#' + [index] + '">' + titles[index] + '</a>';
    },
    before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
      // Do stuff here.
    }

});
```

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

EDIT:

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
  var titles = ['1913', '1918', '1927', '1935', '1950', '1963', '1977', '1980', '1983', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1988-1999', '1990', '1992', '1993', '1993-1995', '1994', '1995', '1999', '1999', '2000', '2003', '2003', '2003', '2003', '2006', '2007-2008', '2011', '2011', '2013'];
  // dynamically add a div to hold the slideshow's pager
  $("#allCardContainer").before('<div id="pager"></div>');

  // now to use the cycle plugin
  $("#allCardContainer").cycle({
    pause: 1,
    pager: "#pager",
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
      return '<a class="scroll" id="link' + [index] + '" href="#' + [index] + '">' + titles[index] + '</a>';
    },
    before: function() {
      if( $('.activeSlide').length > 0) {
        $("#pager").scrollTo($('.activeSlide'), 1500, { axis: 'x', offset:-50 });
      }
    }
  });

  $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#allCardContainer').cycle('pause');
    $('#pager').scrollTo($(this), 1500, { axis: 'x', offset:-50 });
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xFMhA/

Comment: Thank you jSweazy, that worked great. One issue is that the 'before' is firing on every click event now. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: I pause the cycle in the click function.

Comment: Are you trying to change how it rotates. or are you trying to scroll something when it rotates? Also can you put an example jsbin or something like that. If I have your code to work from I can make it work quicker for you

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xFMhA/ but I don't see the pager working in jsfiddle. The image should start rotating in that box and the "active pager link" should scroll to the left. When someone clicks on a year on the timeline that clicked item should scroll to the left at the same place and the cycle should pause indefinitely.

Comment: Ok, I unfortunately do not have time to look right now. I will look back later with a response on how to get it working

Comment: @jsweazy i was looking at your answer because i attempted to use cycle with scrollTo and your fiddle `jsfiddle.net/xFMhA` wouldnt work because your attempting to scroll to `.activeSlide` before cycle can define it.. so your getting a `Uncaught TypeError`